# I am trying to create an Android Library for a Custom Layout which can be fit into all different sized screens

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android Library for a Custom Layout which can be fit into all different sized screens and use that in other projects by adding dependencies. Am not able to know how to create one Library for an Android Layout(*Similar to Relative Layout*). Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is not library it's layout , you can create your own by creating class that extends `ViewGroup`

Comment: Can i get any source link to study on that? or any tutorial videos regarding this?

Comment: I want to make an android library when used that generates a layout created by me. By importing it anyone can use it by adding gradle dependency.